# Set DFP targeting key-values stored in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I am attempting to store a list of DFP key-values in a JSON object and use javascript to loop each key-value pair in the list to set them as page-level targeting parameters in Google Publisher Tags.

```
window.dfpData = {"dfpKV":{"key1":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value1,value2,value3","key4":["value4","value5","value6"]}}
```

I'm using this function, which doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't appear to execute:

```
  if (dfpData.dfpKV) {
for (var i = 0; i < dfpData.dfpKV; i ++) {
  var item = dfpData.dfpKV[i];
  googletag.pubads().setTargeting(item[0], item[1]);
}
```

The resulting output should be the equivalent of multiple lines of:

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key1",["value"]);
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key2",["value2"]);
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key3",["value1,value2,value3"]);
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key4",["value4","value5","value6"]);
```

Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/adopsftw/pen/WzxLqV/):

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not the correct way to loop through the values contained within an object. Try

```
if (dfpData.dfpKV) {
  Object.keys(dfpData.dfpKV).forEach(function(key) {
     googletag.pubads().setTargeting(key, dfpData.dfpKV[key]);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  One further question - for the last two key-value pairs, key3 is a single string value and key4 should be three comma-separated string values (original code below).  

`googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key3",["value1,value2,value3"]);
googletag.pubads().setTargeting("key4",["value4","value5","value6"]);`  

Currently key3 is being set as three separate values.  Is there something I need to add to the function to achieve this?  Ideally, each value should be passed to GPT as `["value"]` for single values or `["value1,"value2"]` for multiple values`

Comment: Try passing the value as string instead of an array. .setTargeting("key3","value1,value2,value3");

Comment: Here's the object I'm looping through - key3 is already a single string value but is being passed as if it was an array of three values:  `window.dfpData = {"dfpKV":{"key1":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value1,value2,value3","key4":["value4","value5","value6"]}}`.  Does the function need something else to output the string as `["value1,value2,value"]`?

Comment: A single value should be passed as a string, not an array containing a string.